# Crear un arbol grafico de directorios y archivos en python

Tags: html, python, django

Saludos me gustaría obtener un **árbol tipo gráfico** de mis carpetas y sus respectivos archivos con `python` actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```
rootDir = 'media/gestionDocumental/'
directorioArr=[]
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    #print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    nombreAbsoluto=dirName.split("/")
    directorioArr.append(nombreAbsoluto[2])
    for fname in fileList:
        #print('\t%s' % fname)
        directorioArr.append(fname)
```

lo cual me da el siguiente resultado:

[image: imagen de arbol actual]

Como puedo mejorar este método ..Gracias de antemano !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo a la pregunta en caso de que alguien la necesite:

**Primero que nada necesitamos conocer el path o rootDir:**

```
rootDir = "mi/directorio/root"
```

luego con esto hacemos un recorrido usando **os.walk** algo asi:

```
list_dir=[]
rootDir = "mi/directorio/root"
            for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
                element={}

                #validamos que no vaya la carpeta root en mi caso no lo deseo
                if dirName != 'media/gestionDocumental/':
                    #nombre original para mostrar 
                    element['carpeta'] = dirName.split('media/gestionDocumental/')
                    #url/ruta esta es la ruta absoluta
                    element['url_carpeta'] = dirName

                    #archivos cada uno de los archivos pertenecientes al folder
                    element['archivos'] = fileList
                    #agregamos element al array
                    list_dir.append(element)
```

con esto ya tendriamos todo en list_dir, visualmente nos quedaria algo asi:
[image: directorios]